# how to display any message upfront exclusive of any software or application running on System

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a software which prompts message on front of the screen like any subliminal Software does and then by counter I will just ignore it in sometime. I am making an application in Java Swing , I would like to know how to prompt any message over any application running.

Like I want to show "Take a Rest , its long Enough" , to the front of the screen ignoring any software running to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a window to always be at the front of screen, you simply have to call `Window.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`. Since Window is an ancestor superclass of `JFrame` and `JDialog`, it will work for your purposes.

With this method, the window will always be visible, even if the user switches to another app. However, the window will only keep in focus if you make it a modal `JDialog` and the user activates the app (i.e. you can't make the window seize focus from another app and then never let it go.). I imagine this by design. It would be really frustrating if a user's entire operating system was made inaccessible by a rogue Java JDialog that could not be closed, although it does mean that you can't have a "Take a Rest , its long Enough" message that truly forces the user to take a break.